# How to convert to lambda expressions

Tags: java, lambda

I have map and i should find value, but value could be null.

```
for (Map.Entry<String, Feature> entry : features.entrySet()) {

        if (entry.getValue().getGroup() != null && entry.getValue().getGroup().getGroupId().equals(groupId)) {
            Features.add(entry.getValue().getName());
        }

    }
```

I know how to do it separately, but I do not know how to do it together. Please help to convert it in lambda expression.

Comment: You’ve got two variables named `features` and `Features`??!

Comment: Start by reading about lambdas and Java stream API. There are plenty of ressources on the net, and courses you may take.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. First you create a `Stream` of the elements you wish to process. In your case, you create a `Stream` of the `entrySet()` of your input `Map`.
2. The `if` statement can be easily converted to a `filter()` call, which keeps only the elements of the `Stream` that pass the `filter`'s `Predicate`.
3. Then you convert any `Entry` of the Stream that passed the filter into `entry.getValue().getName()` (I'm assuming that's a `String`).
4. Finally you can collect these `String`s into some `Collection`. Below I collected the elements into a `List`, but you can use any `Collection` you wish.

   ```
   List<String> featureNames =
       features.entrySet()
               .stream()
               .filter(entry -> entry.getValue().getGroup() != null && entry.getValue().getGroup().getGroupId().equals(groupId))
               .map(entry -> entry.getValue().getName())
               .collect(Collectors.toList());
   ```

As Ole commented, since you make no use of the `Map`'s keys, you can process the `Map`'s values instead of its `entrySet`:

```
List<String> featureNames =
    features.values()
            .stream()
            .filter(feature - > feature.getGroup() != null && feature.getGroup().getGroupId().equals(groupId))
            .map(feature -> feature.getName()) // or .map(Feature::getName)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Comment: Simpler to start from `features.values()`, I think?